# How to count rows for three levels(L1, L2, L3) column and status P for every month in a year

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldO08.png):

[image]

So I want to count the rows for three levels *(L1,L2,L3)* as column and status is `P` for every month in a year.

I want a table like this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ6iH.png) :

[image]

Comment: values  of L1 L2 L3 in new table count of that month and year?

Comment: count of current year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    YEAR (date) AS YEAR,
    MONTH (date) AS MONTH,

IF (
    level_id = 'L1',
    count(level_id),
    0
) AS L1,

IF (
    level_id = 'L2',
    count(level_id),
    0
) AS L2,

IF (
    level_id = 'L3',
    count(level_id),
    0
) AS L3
FROM
    stak
GROUP BY
    date
```

Before the Above query execution :
    [image]

After the Above query executed your desired result: 
    [image]

Comment: where are level three(L3) i want all three levels plz.

Comment: SELECT year(date) as year, month(date) as month ,if( level_id = 'L1',count(level_id), 0) as L1 ,if( level_id = 'L2',count(level_id), 0) as L2,if( level_id = 'L3',count(level_id), 0) as L3 FROM stak GROUP BY date